# Nginx configuration file does not work as expected

Tags: nginx, docker

I have a docker running Nginx on port 80 and I port forwarded to 8080, so I can see it locally in localhost:8080

Using ngrok I created a url. Using the newly created url I can see the Welcome Page of Nginx locally. Lets say my url is http://myurl.ngrok.io/

All I want now is Nginx to listen to requests and if I ask http://myurl.ngrok.io/mylocation
it will return 200 and print YES!!!.

This is how I configured nginx.conf:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
       listen 8080 default_server;
       server_name _;
       add_header X-debug-message "A static file was served" always;
       return 200;

       location \mylocation {
           return 200 'YES!!!';
       }
    }
}
```

After I configured nginx.conf file I hit:

```
root@ec24***f108:/etc/nginx# nginx -s reload
2021/02/21 13:47:55 [notice] 1048#1048: signal process started
```

Then going to http://myurl.ngrok.io/mylocation I get 404!

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have a `return 200;` in the `server` block, which will be processed before the `location` statements. Only put `return` statements in the `server` block if that is the only thing the `server` block needs to do, otherwise, it need to be inside another block.

The `location` statement literally matches the URI `/*`. If you want a `location` that matches any URI, use `location /`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

Comment: I removed the     return 200; from the server block. However, it does not work yet. It should print a debug message "A static file was served" and it doesn't do it. Also, for now I don't mind at this step to match any URI, just want to see it's working as first step.

Answer (score 0):

```
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
```

This line means that *.conf (any .conf file) will get higher priority than nginx.conf (the file I showed in my question).

Inside /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf there is a server { } section that gets loaded anytime I asked for the site, and the server { } I wrote in nginx.conf was not considered.

All I had to do is to mark out the include line from nginx.conf, and then reload the Nginx with

```
nginx -s reload
```

Now every time the page is loaded, the nginx.conf is considered.